# Compute Instance not starting

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a free tier account and I had an free tier eligible instance created few months ago. I was able to ssh into the instance then. After few months I am trying to start the instance now but it does not start. After clicking on start, it says starting initially but then it stops. Not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: You're probably better off with contacting support or just recreating the instance.

Comment: Try creating a new instance and see if it works. If that works, then you can terminate your first instance without deleting the boot volume. From this boot volume you can create a new instance.